# How to install Hunspell for C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, hunspell, nhunspell

I want to implement spell check and dictionary in my C# windows-based application. From Google, I found that **hunspell** is one of the best options to implement this functionality. I have installed **nhunspell** using visual studio NuGet as per the suggestion from the below URL. But when I try to execute the code, getting error "AFF File not found: C:\TestProject\TestHunshell\bin\Debug\en_us.aff"

When I search the installed hunspell package .aff & .dic files are not found. I am not sure from where I can download and install or paste "en_us.aff", "en_us.dic" files to my solution.

Can someone please suggest the proper way to install and implement hunspell in the C# windows application?

[Code Project Reference URL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43495/Spell-Check-Hyphenation-and-Thesaurus-for-NET-with)

[image: Error]

Comment: The nuget package was last updated 2015, homepage as well as sourcecode seem to be not there. I would consider this as deprecated and not maintained anymore

Comment: @Sascha If possible, Can you please suggest some alternate URL to implement the same functionality in C#.

Comment: If you take a look at the [hunspell project page](http://hunspell.github.io/) there are links to some dictionaries there.

Comment: @phuzi I tried https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/en/en_US.dic but I am unable to download .aff & .dic files.

Comment: From that link there's a link to the plain file, try downloading that!

Comment: @phuzi - Yes, I tried that option. Able to download .aff file but .dic file always getting downloaded as txt only. Even if I try save as option, it is not  getting saved as .dic file.

Comment: Can't you just rename the file? It does appear to be plain text!

Comment: @phuzi  I renamed the file but it is not working as expected. If possible, can you please suggest any alternate URL to implement this functionality in C#.

Comment: @Ask_SO, please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, you could download `aff & .dic files` from the following link:

[en_US.aff](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.aff)

[en_US.dic](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.dic)

After clicking on the click, we should right-click to save as a txt file.

Then, we need to move the .txt to change it to the extension .aff or .dic.

Finally, we move the two files to the `project\bin\debug` folder.

Here is my test code and result:

```
    Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_US.aff", "en_US.dic");
    Console.WriteLine("Hunspell - Spell Checking Functions");
    Console.WriteLine("¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯");

    Console.WriteLine("Check if the word 'Recommendation' is spelled correct");
    bool correct = hunspell.Spell("Recommendation");
    Console.WriteLine("Recommendation is spelled " +
       (correct ? "correct" : "not correct"));

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Make suggestions for the word 'Recommendatio'");
    List<string> suggestions = hunspell.Suggest("Recommendatio");
    Console.WriteLine("There are " +
       suggestions.Count.ToString() + " suggestions");
    foreach (string suggestion in suggestions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Suggestion is: " + suggestion);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it is not working for me. I downloaded the files and renamed with correct extensions. but in the suggestions, value is always empty.

Comment: @Ask_SO, You could download the two files from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ast0x04bo32WrCaWHtfkGr1aZ7q6?e=Dhe2P6).

Comment: J Jun - Can you plz briefly explain me the purpose of AFF file. Even if any reference link also fine.